# Why kABPersonPhoneProperty is not visible to swift?

Tags: addressbook, xcode6

In the code below,

```
import Foundation

import AddressBook

let pty = kABPersonPhoneProperty;
```

swift flags `kABPersonPhoneProperty` as a unresolved identifier.

[image]
Why it is the case?

I am using XCode Beta3